# Parametrization of a curve

Tags: performance, c, computational-geometry

For a set of 2D or 3D points \$\{\mathbf P_0, \mathbf P_1,\cdots,\mathbf P_n\}\$, their parameters \$\mathbf T = \{t_0,t_1,\cdots,t_n \}\$ could be computed as follow:

$$\begin{align}
t_0&=0\\
t_i&=\frac{\sum_{j=1}^{i}||\mathbf P_j- \mathbf P_{j-1}||}{\sum_{j=1}^{n}||\mathbf P_j-\mathbf P_{j-1}||} \qquad i=1,2,\cdots,n
\end{align}$$

Here is my C implementation:

```
/********************************************************************
         v1 = {v1(0),v1(1),...,v1(c-1)}  
         v2 = {v2(0),v2(1),...,v2(c-1)}
     compute the 2-norm of the difference of two vector v1 and v2
*********************************************************************/
double vector_norm(double *v1, double *v2, int c) {
    int i;
    double res = 0.0;
    for (i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        res += pow(v1[i] - v2[i], 2);
    }
    return sqrt(res);
}

/********************************************************
 In general, P is a matrix of dimensions {n + 1, c}
 here, it was saved as a vector
********************************************************/
void calc_paras(double *P, int n, int c, double *paras) {
    int i;
    double len = 0.0;
    double chord;
    //compute the length and total length
    paras[0] = 0.0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        chord = vector_norm(P + (i + 1) * c, P + i * c, c);
        len += chord;
        paras[i+1] = len;
    }
    //normalize the paras to [0,1]
    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        paras[i] /= len;
    }
}
```

Is a more efficient C implemetation of `calc_paras()` possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is a more efficient C implementation of `calc_paras()` possible?

Some small ideas:

1. Use `const`.  A compiler may employ certain optimizations knowing the pointers are to `const` data.

   ```
   // double vector_norm(double *v1, double *v2, int c) {
   double vector_norm(const double *v1, const double *v2, int c) {
   ```
2. If the pointers never overlap, let the compiler know that and allow it additional optimizations using `restrict`.

   ```
   // double vector_norm(double *v1, double *v2, int c) {
   double vector_norm(const double * restrict v1, const double * restrict v2, int c) {
   ```
3. `pow(x,2)` is questionable.  Profile against `res += (v1[i] - v2[i])*(v1[i] - v2[i]);`
4. Unclear why code is using `int` vs. `size_t` to denote the size of a vector.   `size_t` is more C-like.
5. Minor. Might as well avoid the +1

   ```
   paras[0] = 0.0;
   for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
     chord = vector_norm(P + i*c, P + (i-1)* c, c);
     len += chord;
     paras[i] = len;
   }
   ```
6. If `vector_norm()` is only meant as a helper function for `calc_paras()`, make `vector_norm()` `static` to un-clutter the name space.

Comment: Thanks a lot:)  For a C newcomer, I would like to know why `pow(x, 2)` is questionable. Because `pow()` is a built-in of `math.h` library.

Comment: `pow()` is one of the most complex math functions.  Rarely is `pow(x,2)` more efficient/more precise than simply `x*x`.  I have doubts as to its relative value and speed. Like much minor optimizations, profile it on your target platforms.  When in doubt, code to what provides the most clarity to a reviewer.

Comment: In addtion, I discovered that the compiler gives the error when using keywords `restrict`. Here is [snapshots](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OGL5a.png)

Comment: @Shutao Tang Use an up-to-date C11 compiler if you are interested in modern optimizations, else your code lives in the past.  If obiged to use an old complier why look for a "more efficient C implementation"?

Comment: As a side note for 5. Both temporaries are unecessary. If you zero-initialize paras[0], then the body of the for loop can be written as 
  paras[i] = paras[i-1] +vector_norm(P + i * c, P + (i-1) * c, c); However, i assume the compiler would be able to optimize that away. Also the loop should stop at <n at leaast from the vector definition in the first code snipplet

Comment: @miscco OP's code snippet uses `for (i = 0; i < n; i++) { ... paras[i+1]`.  I was recommending `or (i = 1; i <= n; i++) { ... paras[i]` (notice difference in index assignment and usage)  to closer match  OP's t(i) equation.

Comment: Yes, but int the original code we have `v1 = {v1(0),v1(1),...,v1(c-1)}`, so i think there is an off by one error.

Answer (score 2):

That is basically the same technique that I would use.

My only suggestion is to consistently use

```
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
```

for both loops, to match the stated definition.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I know `for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)` is C99 style, but when I compile it via the `CreateLibrary[]`of Wolfram Mathematica, I discovered that it didn't support that style.

Comment: It's really sad that C99 still isn't supported in 2016!

Comment: Maybe I don't know what option I should add in `CreateLibrary[]` to let the code be compiled with C99 style. :)